# TAM categories: Can they be predicted from their numbers (a language's TAM inventory size)?

Tags: morphology, linguistic-typology, linguistic-universals, morphosyntax, morphological-typology

To some extent, *vowels* can be predicted based on the size of the vowel inventory, so, for example, in a 3-vowel system, it will be /a i u/, whereas in a 4-vowel system, we will get /a i u ɛ/ or /a i u ɨ/ etc. (based on Crothers 1978). We can also predict consonants, to a limited degree, based on their numbers, place of articulation etc. In addition, we can predict the colour terms based on the number of colours distinguished in the system.

Hence, I would like to know what kind of implicational tree can one draw when we think of the TAM categories (separately - as *tense*, *aspect* and *mood* - or as a bundle), e.g. if a language only has two tenses, what are they (not)?

I could imagine something like this:

- 2 tenses: *past* vs. *non-past* or *future* vs. *non-future*
- 3 tenses: *past* vs. *present* vs. *future*
- 4 tenses: *past I* vs. *present I* vs. *past II* vs. *present II*

etc.

I will be grateful for any relevant references too.

Answer (score 1):

For a starter, you may look up the Wikipedia article on Grammatical Tense (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_tense). Besides *past vs non-past* you can also find *future vs. non-future* in a two-tense system, e.g., in Quechua.

Comment: Thank you, the article is a good start, indeed. I wonder then, if it is always the non-past / non-future that is more marked than the past / future in the two-tense systems, ie whther it is always the tense encompassing the _present_ athat is _less marked_. I will have a look at the references to see if I can find the information.

Comment: @Pavel Jetušek This is another question (and may be worth asking, after some reading)

Comment: You may find the various "Verbal Categories" papers [chapters 65-80 in WALS](http://wals.info/chapter) useful, then. There isn't one on TAM together, but all the various pieces are there.

Comment: @jlawler That's a wonderful piece of advice! I keep forgetting it's there - online and free! Thanks a lot!